# PHP extension in C. How do I call a Fortran subroutine with a character string argument?

Tags: php, c, fortran

I am writing a PHP extension in C which makes calls to subroutines in a Fortran library. I am able to call subroutines which require `int` or `double` arguments, but I can't figure out how to pass a character string. Here is a snippet of the Fortran subroutine source (which I cannot change):

```
Subroutine abcdef(stringA)

  Character *(*) stringA

  .................
  ................. 

  Return
End Subroutine abcdef
```

And here is my attempt in the C extension:

```
extern void abcdef_(char *strA, int *size);
PHP_FUNCTION(abcdef)
{
  char *_strA;
  int size;

  /* Arguments Parsing */
  if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "s",
                &_strA, &size) == FAILURE)
    {
      RETURN_NULL();
    } 

  abcdef_(_strA, &size);

  return;
}
```

Maybe I'm searching the wrong things, but I've found information on this pretty scarce. Am I right in thinking `Character *(*)` is just a pointer to a Character array? I've tried many different combinations for the parameters and can't seem to get it right. Sometimes when I call the routine it segfaults, other times PHP shows no error but the subroutine has no effect.

Due to the fact that I am able to call routines with int and double parameters from my extension, and that this routine works fine when called from Fortran, I think it must be the way I'm passing the string, but just can't work out the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a compiler specific thing. The best thing would be to use the Fortran 2003 C interoperability. Even if you cannot change (why?) the original code, you can always write a wrapper layer in Fortran 2003 with `bind(C)`.

If you cannot do that, consult your compiler's ABI. For gfortran http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Argument-passing-conventions.html suggests that you should pass the size by value.

That means:

str.f90:

```
subroutine str(s)
  character*(*) :: s
  print *,s
end subroutine
```

passstr.c:

```
void str_(char * s, int size);
int main(){
 str_("Hello",5);
}
```

compile and run:

```
>gfortran str.f90 passstr.c
> ./a.out 
 Hello
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had tried that already. The problem must be something else, but at least I know this is correct now so I can pinpoint the actual problem.

Comment: But in the code in your question you were using `&size`, I hope you are aware of that.